# transform.position in Player class is null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can not figure out why the transform of the object the player script is attached to is returning null.

this is the Controller Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    Player player = new Player();
    void Start()
    {
        player.SetEndpos(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            int roll = Random.Range(1, 7);
            player.SetEndpos(new Vector3(roll, 0f, 0f));
        }
        player.Run();
    }
}
```

This is the Player code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 endPos = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);

    public void Run()
    {
        if (transform.position != null)
        {
            transform.position += endPos;
            if (endPos != new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f))
            {
                Debug.Log($"pos was set to: {endPos}");
            }
        }
    }

    public Vector3 GetEndpos()
    {
        return endPos;
    }

    public void SetEndpos(Vector3 end)
    {
        endPos = end;
        Debug.Log($"endPos = {endPos}");
    }
}
```

The null error is given at "transform.position += endPos;" in Player and "player.Run();" in Controller

The exact error message:
NullReferenceException
Player.Run () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:11)
Controller.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Controller.cs:20)

Image:
[Manager Object has Controller script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ocdh.jpg)

Image:
[Player Object has the Player script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csnUd.jpg)

I'm sure its some stupid error I have made but I cant find a solution to this anywhere else online.

Comment: `transform` itself might be null. Check with `if (transform?.position != null)` or simply `if (transform != null)`

Comment: Why would `player` have a `transform` if it is never attached to a GameObject? See: `Player player = new Player();`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/09EXgnq.jpeg !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to replace the `Player player = new Player();` line with 
`public Player player;`
or

```
[Serializable]
private Player player;
```

inside your controller script.
After that you will see a change in the inspector window of your controller. There should be an empty field which states "None (Player)".
Take your `Player` GameObject inside your hierachy and drag it into the empty field inside the empty field.